# Laravel | Compare two collections and echo their attributes based on their created_at and deleted_at fields

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, merge, laravel-5.4

I want to display an activity list for my loan management laravel application
So a **in a day a loan might be granted(`created_at`) or a loan could be closed/completed(`deleted_at`).**

I am fetching these two collections using:

```
$new_loans = loan::withTrashed()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->get();

$completed_loans = loan::onlyTrashed()->where('deleted_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->get();
```

My problem is I want to display the attributes of these two collections dynamically based on when a loan was created and when a loan was closed.

**Suppose:**

```
    new_loans   | completed_loans

   1 - 10 am    | 3 - 8 am

   2 - 12 am    | 4- 11 am
```

The output should be :

**Activities**:

- 3 - 8 am, loan closed
- 1 - 10 am, New Loan
- 4 - 11 am, loan closed
- 2 - 12 am, new loan

I tried to write some logic using `foreach` and `ifs` but its is clearly wrong,

```
    foreach ($new_loans as $new) 
    {
        foreach ($completed_loans as $comp)
         {

            if($comp->deleted_at > $new->created_at)
            {
            echo $new->customer->first_name.'----- New---'.$new->created_at->diffForHumans()."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo $comp->customer->first_name.'----- Completed---'.$comp->deleted_at->diffForHumans()."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine the entire thing into one query and then sort the result for the desired order.

You should also be [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the `customer` relation so that you're not executing a new query for each loop.

All that put together would look like:

```
$loans = loan::with('customer')
    ->withTrashed()
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        return $query->whereNotNull('deleted_at')
            ->where('deleted_at', '>=', Carbon::today());
    })
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function($loan) {
        return $loan->deleted_at === null ? $loan->created_at : $loan->deleted_at;
    });

foreach ($loans as $loan) {
    if($loan->deleted_at === null) {
        echo $loan->customer->first_name.'----- New---'.$loan->created_at->diffForHumans()."<br>";
    } else {
        echo $loan->customer->first_name.'----- Completed---'.$loan->deleted_at->diffForHumans()."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent but there is a problem with this query I think, whenever a loan is completed(deleted) then in the results the respective created notification is also appearing.

Comment: like if a loan is completed, I get the output like `Ronak----- New---3 days ago
Ronak----- Completed---4 seconds ago`, I need only the happenings on the current day

Comment: I've updated the answer so it only echoes one or the other as in your example